# how to shade before compile with SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

[Our project](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump) mainly consists of two parts

- [Build.scala](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump/blob/master/project/Build.scala) where the root project lies
- [BuildShaded.scala](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump/blob/master/project/BuildShaded.scala) where some external dependencies are shaded with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly). The shaded jars will be depended upon by sub projects under the root project through `unmanagedJars` setting.

The question is how to assembly the shaded project before compiling the root project. Otherwise, the root project will fail to compile since those classes in the shaded jars are not available.

Comment: Why are you using a separate build to shade the external dependencies? Why not take them as managed dependencies and shade them inside the `Build.scala` root?

Comment: because I need to depend on the classes after shading. "managed dependencies" will introduce classes before shading.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you shade the project both `inLibrary` and `inProject`, it will shed the *internal dependencies* as well.

Comment: what do you mean ? Do you have any examples or documentation ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I would take a different route. If you take on the dependencies as *managed dependencies*, you can shade them both in the library itself and inside your project.

Let's see an example:

Assume that I have a project which takes dependency on `com.typesafe.config`. I can shade it inside it's own library, meaning inside the code of `com.typesafe.config`, and also in the consuming library.

You define it like this:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.typesafe.config.**" -> "my_conf.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0")
    .inProject
)
```

Which basically means "take any package that beings with `com.typesafe.config` and shade it to `my_conf`."

Note that we're using both `inLibrary` and `inProject`. The former means "change the package names and references to them inside `com.typesafe.config`" and `inProject` means "change all references to `com.typesafe.config` inside my code".

Now, the output of that looks like this:

This is how the package internally looks now (`my_conf` was originally `com.typesafe.config` before shading):

[image: Typesafe Config code]

And this is the package your code will reference:

[image: Your Code]

Comment: "managed dependencies" don't seem to work. The depending projects fail to compile with the shaded classes not found. By "managed dependencies" you mean like `Project("core").dependsOn(shaded)`  ? By the way, how is `inLibrary.inProject` different from `inAll` ?

Comment: @manuzhang No, by managed dependencies I mean dependencies managed by SBT. Can you show an example of a `build.sbt` so we can fit the shading with it.

Comment: I finally understood what you mean and shading the depending projects with managed dependencies works. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/apache/incubator-gearpump/blob/master/project/BuildGearpump.scala) is our build file finally. The approach is not so clean that I have to manually add/remove dependencies in the published pom file though.

Comment: Your answer is slightly misleading. `inLibrary` means: change packages name AND references.

Comment: @tomek.xyz Edited for clarity