# In project dependency shade rename

Tags: maven, sbt, maven-shade-plugin

As it can be read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40404371/1893995), SBT (sbt-assembly) allows package renaming in the project that is importing the renamed library. e.g:

I want to use the package `org.pfcoperez.algorithms` in my project but I want to "see" it, that is: be able to import it, as `com.algorithms`.

I know that Maven Shade Plugin can relocate dependencies as described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html):

```
         <relocations>
            <relocation>
              <pattern>org.codehaus.plexus.util</pattern>
              <shadedPattern>org.shaded.plexus.util</shadedPattern>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom</exclude>
                <exclude>org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </relocation>
          </relocations>
```

I could use that to generate an intermediate jar having the new package structure. However, I'd like to avoid using that intermediate artifact.

Is it possible to do this in a Maven project as it is in SBT? If the answer is yes, how could it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can attach the `shade:shade` goal to the `process-resources` phase and set up the generated jar as a `system` dependency, so that it's available during the `compile` phase.

I wouldn't recommend it however, as your IDE is almost certainly going to have problems understanding your POM.