# sbt assembly assemblyShadeRules not shading dependency

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt, sbt-assembly, sbt-plugin

I am trying to shade com.google.gson to my_gson and added assemblyShadeRules to my build.sbt:

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.gson.**" -> "my_gson.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.9")
    .inProject
)
```

According to this:
[how to shade before compile with SBT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397065/how-to-shade-before-compile-with-sbt)
when we shade the dependency using assemblyShadeRules, the import statement should change and be updated from e.g.

```
import com.google.gson.{Gson, JsonArray, JsonObject}
```

into `my_gson.{Gson, JsonArray, JsonObject}`

The thing is it is still shwoing as `com.google.gson`
I am unsure why. i am currently using intellij as my IDE but the change is not reflected even after i did the shading as per My build.sbt here:

```
name := "CMS Leakage Detection"

version := "3.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.15"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.3.0",
  "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.9",
  "com.google.cloud.spark" %% "spark-bigquery-with-dependencies" % "0.26.0" % "provided",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.2",
  "com.jcraft" % "jsch" % "0.1.55",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-web" % "5.3.18",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.4.15",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.5.13"
)

excludeDependencies ++= Seq(
  ExclusionRule("org.apache.hadoop", "commons-logging")
)

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-Xmax-classfile-name","80")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _                        => MergeStrategy.first
}

assemblyShadeRules in assembly ++= Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.gson.**" -> "my_gson.@1")
    .inLibrary("com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.8.9")
    .inProject
)
```

I am expecting the import statement to show:
e.g.)

```
import my_gson.JsonObject
```

running `jar tvf .../path-to-my-jar` is also showing that the dependency is not shaded, output:
`Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 SGT 2010 com/google/gson/JsonObject.class`

i created a file called plugins.sbt inside my project folder
/Users/myname/Desktop/repo/projIamWorkingOn/project/plugins.sbt
and it contains only the following, its so that i can use sbt assembly

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "1.2.0")
```